# How to format a number with optional fraction

Tags: postgresql, number-formatting

Is it possible to format a number in Postgresql with optional fraction?  Like:

```
1.0 -> '1'
1.3 -> '1.3'
```

I looked into `to_char`, but I don't get much further than '1.' with `to_char(1.0, 'FM9D9')`.

Is it possible, and how? I'm using Postgresql 9.5

Comment: Why do you want that?  Isn't formatting the output a task for the application/client?

Comment: You can remove the trailing period: `trim(trailing '.' from to_char(1.0, 'FM9D9'))`

Comment: I just want to do this within a query for now (because sometimes it comes in handy) and I'm new to Postgresql, and a like learning new things. It doesn't look like it's possible, without the trim solution.. A well, `1.0` also looks nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`trim(trailing '.0', x::text)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html)

```
SELECT trim(trailing '.0' FROM x::text)
FROM (
  VALUES (1.5),(1.0),(1.04),(1.040),(1.9594830000)
) AS t(x);
  rtrim   
----------
 1.5
 1
 1.04
 1.04
 1.959483
(5 rows)
```